# C: Global ,Static variables understanding

Tags: c, variables

In following program  . I have one doubt. I have declared one global variable . I am
printing the address of the global variable in the function . It is giving me same address 
when I am not changing the value of global .  If I did any changes in the global variables 
It is giving me different address  why...........? Like that it is happening for static also.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int global=10 ; // Global variables

void function();

main()
{
        global=20;
        printf ( " %p \n" , global ) ;
        printf ( " Val: %d\n", global ) ;
        function();
        new();
}

void function()
{
        global=30;
        printf ( " %p \n" , global ) ;
        printf ( " Val: %d\n", global ) ;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not printing the address of the variable.

To print the address:

```
printf("%p\n", &global);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not printing the address of the global, you are printing its value. To print the address:

```
printf ( " %p \n" , & global ) ;
```

Note the ampersand, which is the "address-of" operator. The "%p" formatter only controls output format, it doesn't make printf() magically take the address for you.